# Ladda spin animation keeps spinning for one second after stop()

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [ladda spinner](http://msurguy.github.io/ladda-bootstrap/) like this:

```
var l = Ladda.create(document.getElementById('ladda-test'));
l.start();
l.stop();
console.log('ladda is stoped');
```

My problem is that after `l.stop()` is executed, the animation does not instantly stop: the spin animation only stops after one second.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timeout function to wait one second - then execute your code.

> The setTimeout() method will wait the specified number of
>   milliseconds, and then execute the specified function.
>
> The first parameter of setTimeout() should be a function.
>
> The second parameter indicates how many milliseconds, from now, you
>   want to execute the first parameter.

For example:

```
var l = Ladda.create(document.getElementById('ladda-test'));
l.start();
setTimeout(function() {
    l.stop();
    console.log('ladda is stoped');
}, 2000); // This unit equates to two seconds
```

You can learn more about timing events here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: Now delay two seconds: one sec. for setTimeout and second sec. before after l.stop() animate showing one second...

Comment: @codelife Could you please try to explain your comment again? The timeout doesn't need to be delayed by one second. That's the whole point of a timeout - it doesn't execute until after one second.

Comment: If you want to increase the delay, just change the 1000 milliseconds to 2000 milliseconds.

Comment: Problem in Ladda library not in other something other. Ladda library have methods start() and stop() when i call start() immediately show spin (like progress loading) and when i call stop() only after one second animation dissapear (animation is spin loading progress)

Comment: James, I believe _codelife_ didn't want to delay the animation, he just wanted it to stop immediately after `l.stop()`...

Comment: It happens if you have explicitly set the opacity of the spinner in your CSS somewhere. Ladda appears to spin even after stoping for a second.